# android async not updating listview?

Tags: android, listview, android-asynctask

Whenever I step thought the code slowly I get my result as expected on the result tab, but when I run the code as normal I get not results in the result tab, Any help will be greatly appreciated.

here is class Hummmedia.java class, the main one:

```
package edu.byu.hummedia;

import android.app.ActionBar;

import android.app.ActionBar.Tab;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Hummedia extends Activity implements ActionBar.TabListener {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    ListView myListView = null;
    public ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    Button basicSubmitButton;
    Button advancedSubmitButton;
    EditText myBasicEditText;
    EditText myAdvancedEditText;
    EditText title;
    EditText language;
    EditText category;
    EditText keyword;
    ActionBar bar;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);


       bar = getActionBar();
       bar.addTab(bar.newTab().setText("Basic\nSearch").setTabListener(this));
       bar.addTab(bar.newTab().setText("Advanced\nSearch").setTabListener(this));
       bar.addTab(bar.newTab().setText("Results").setTabListener(this));
       //bar.addTab(bar.newTab().setText("Exit").setTabListener(this));

       bar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM | ActionBar.DISPLAY_USE_LOGO);
       bar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
       bar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
       // remove the activity title to make space for tabs
       bar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
       bar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);
    }

    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (tab.getText().equals("Basic\nSearch"))
        {
             Toast.makeText(this, "Searching for: " + "basic" + "...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        if (tab.getText().equals("Advanced\nSearch"))
        {
             Toast.makeText(this, "Searching for: " + "Advanced" + "...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        if (tab.getText().equals("Results"))
        {
             Toast.makeText(this, "Searching for: " + "Results" + "...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (tab.getText().equals("Basic\nSearch"))
        {
             setContentView(R.layout.basic);
             basicSubmitButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.myBasicSubmitbutton);
             myBasicEditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.myBasicEditText);
        }
        if (tab.getText().equals("Advanced\nSearch"))
        {
            setContentView(R.layout.advanced);
             advancedSubmitButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.myAdvancedSubmitbutton);
             title = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.title);
             language = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.language);
             category = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.category);
             keyword = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.keyword);
            //Toast.makeText(this, "Searching for: " + "Advanced" + "...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
        if (tab.getText().equals("Results"))
        {
            setContentView(R.layout.results);

             //Toast.makeText(this, "Searching for: " + "Results" + "...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    public void basicSubmitButton(View view) {
        String query = myBasicEditText.getText().toString();
        bar.setSelectedNavigationItem(2);
        ReadWebpageAsyncTask basicSubmission = new ReadWebpageAsyncTask();
        basicSubmission.query(query);
        myListView = (ListView) findViewById (R.id.lv);
        myListView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
        myListView.clearChoices();


        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Hummedia.this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                basicSubmission.mediaList);
        myListView.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }


    public void advancedSubmitButton(View view) {
        String mytitle = title.getText().toString();
        String mylanguage = language.getText().toString();
        String mycategory = category.getText().toString();
        String mykeyword = keyword.getText().toString();
        String query="";
        if (mytitle.isEmpty() != true)
        {
            query+="title="+mytitle;
        }
        if (mylanguage.isEmpty() != true)
        {
            query+="language="+mylanguage;
        }
        if (mycategory.isEmpty() != true)
        {
            query+="subject="+mycategory;
        }
        if (mykeyword.isEmpty() != true)
        {
            query+="keyword="+mykeyword;
        }
        //Toast.makeText(this, "I was called...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        bar.setSelectedNavigationItem(2);
        ReadWebpageAsyncTask advancedSubmission = new ReadWebpageAsyncTask();
        advancedSubmission.advquery(query);
        myListView = (ListView) findViewById (R.id.lv);
        myListView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
        myListView.clearChoices();


        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Hummedia.this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                advancedSubmission.mediaList);
        myListView.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }


    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

and here is my async class:

```
package edu.byu.hummedia;

import java.io.BufferedReader;

import android.widget.Toast;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.json.JSONArray;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.Toast;
public class ReadWebpageAsyncTask extends ListActivity  {
    private TextView textView;
    public ListView myListView = null;
    List<String> mediaList = new ArrayList();
    public ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    String[] newArray;
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //setContentView(R.layout.main);
        String[] values = new String[] { "Android", "iPhone", "WindowsMobile",
                "Blackberry", "WebOS", "Ubuntu", "Windows7", "Max OS X",
                "Linux", "OS/2" };
        newArray = new String[mediaList.size()];mediaList.toArray(newArray);
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, newArray);
        setListAdapter(adapter);    
        readWebpage(myListView);



    }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        String item = (String) getListAdapter().getItem(position);
        Toast.makeText(this, item + " selected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    }



    private class DownloadWebPageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
            String response = "";
            String responseBuilder;
            String responseString = "";
            JSONArray jsonArray;
            JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject();

            for (String url : urls) {
                DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
                try {
                    HttpResponse execute = client.execute(httpGet);
                    InputStream content = execute.getEntity().getContent();

                    BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(
                            new InputStreamReader(content));
                    String s = "";
                    while ((s = buffer.readLine()) != null) {
                        response += s;
                    }

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            try {
                jsonArray = new org.json.JSONArray(response);
                jObject = jsonArray.toJSONObject(jsonArray);

                for (int i=0;i<jObject.length();i++)
                {
                    responseBuilder="\n";
                    responseBuilder+= "\n title: "+((JSONObject) jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).get("videoinfo")).get("title");
                    responseBuilder+= "\n subject: "+ ((JSONObject) jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).get("videoinfo")).get("subject");
                    responseBuilder+= "\n language: "+ ((JSONObject) jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).get("videoinfo")).get("language");


                    mediaList.add(responseBuilder); 
                    responseString += responseBuilder;
                }



            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return responseString;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        }
    }


    public void readWebpage(View view) {
        DownloadWebPageTask task = new DownloadWebPageTask();
        task.execute(new String[] { "http://hummedia.byu.edu/mediainfo/search/?title=Harry" });

    }

    public void query(String query) {
        DownloadWebPageTask task = new DownloadWebPageTask();
        task.execute(new String[] { "http://hummedia.byu.edu/mediainfo/search/?keyword="+query});

    }

    public void advquery(String query) {
        DownloadWebPageTask task = new DownloadWebPageTask();
        task.execute(new String[] { "http://hummedia.byu.edu/mediainfo/search/?"+query});

    }

}
```

and finally here is my logcat stack trace with no issues i may add:

```
12-05 22:58:18.766: W/ActivityThread(2138): Application edu.byu.hummedia is waiting for the debugger on port 8100...
12-05 22:58:18.826: I/System.out(2138): Sending WAIT chunk
12-05 22:58:18.838: I/dalvikvm(2138): Debugger is active
12-05 22:58:19.026: I/System.out(2138): Debugger has connected
12-05 22:58:19.026: I/System.out(2138): waiting for debugger to settle...
12-05 22:58:19.226: I/System.out(2138): waiting for debugger to settle...
12-05 22:58:19.436: I/System.out(2138): waiting for debugger to settle...
12-05 22:58:19.636: I/System.out(2138): waiting for debugger to settle...
12-05 22:58:19.837: I/System.out(2138): waiting for debugger to settle...
12-05 22:58:20.036: I/System.out(2138): waiting for debugger to settle...
12-05 22:58:20.236: I/System.out(2138): waiting for debugger to settle...
12-05 22:58:20.479: I/System.out(2138): waiting for debugger to settle...
12-05 22:58:20.736: I/System.out(2138): waiting for debugger to settle...
12-05 22:58:20.936: I/System.out(2138): waiting for debugger to settle...
12-05 22:58:21.176: I/System.out(2138): waiting for debugger to settle...
12-05 22:58:21.448: I/System.out(2138): waiting for debugger to settle...
12-05 22:58:21.705: I/System.out(2138): waiting for debugger to settle...
12-05 22:58:21.917: I/System.out(2138): waiting for debugger to settle...
12-05 22:58:22.136: I/System.out(2138): debugger has settled (1485)
12-05 22:58:25.196: D/gralloc_goldfish(2138): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
12-05 22:58:38.736: D/dalvikvm(2138): GC_CONCURRENT freed 211K, 4% free 10169K/10503K, paused 20ms+15ms
12-05 22:58:39.075: D/dalvikvm(2138): GC_CONCURRENT freed 456K, 7% free 10166K/10823K, paused 25ms+15ms
12-05 22:58:39.336: D/dalvikvm(2138): GC_CONCURRENT freed 403K, 6% free 10194K/10823K, paused 14ms+14ms
12-05 22:58:39.527: D/dalvikvm(2138): GC_CONCURRENT freed 425K, 7% free 10161K/10823K, paused 14ms+5ms
12-05 22:58:39.790: D/dalvikvm(2138): GC_CONCURRENT freed 389K, 7% free 10164K/10823K, paused 14ms+13ms
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because you display data from AsyncTask which is not completed its task, So **either wait for it completes (display progress dialog)** or I think you have to implement  `onProgressUpdate()` in your AsyncTask and `publishProgress(..);` from your `doINBackground()` which **update your list at some interval**.

Something like, (This is for example)

```
protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
         setProgressPercent(progress[0]);
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

The async task may not be completed before u try the result tab. Add progress for ur async task and block the screen till it is completed. Then click results.